# MAAS server network configuration

Tags: maas

Scenario:

MAAS Server:  10.1.1.100/24 [VLAN1]
Physical Server IPMI (Dell iDRACs): 10.1.2.0/24 [VLAN2]
Physical Server OS Management Network: 10.2.3.0/24 [VLAN3]

I believe IPMI is from MAAS > iDRACs and PXE/DHCP is from MAAS > OS Management Network.

So, should the MAAS server have three network adapters, one in each VLAN?  Or two adapters - one for VLAN1, and a trunk for VLANs 2 and 3?  What's the best way to setup a single MAAS server's networking?

And, if using a trunk port for multiple VLANs, what config is required in the OS before installing MAAS?  Do I need to create the sub interfaces for each vlan, or just handle the config inside MAAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use of multiple network interfaces on MAAS is a hassle and unnecessary for most deployments.  You only need a single network interface.  Just make sure your host vlans are forwarding DHCP requests to MAAS (e.g. Cisco IP helpers).  If you use multiple nics, you may need to account for asymmetric routing issues when MAAS wants to reach hosts using secondary network connections while the hosts want to reach MAAS using MAAS's primary management nic.